# Calibration plot error - Non-Numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, plot, calibration

I am unable to produce a calibration plot for my logistic classification model, and I am unsure of why I am getting this error / how to fix it.

For the purposes of reproducibility, here is a made up example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(classifierplots)
test.df <- as_tibble(data_frame(y = factor(c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1)),pred = c(0.1,0.15,0.2,0.05,0.6,0.7,0.2,0.85,0.1,0.75)))
calibration_plot(test.y = test.df$y,pred.prob = test.df$pred)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error in alpha * 255 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Similarly, when I run the code with my actual model, I receive the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't replicate the error with the data you showed - i.e. it is working fine and creating the plot.  Is it based on the same example or different?

Comment: I am getting an error with this exact test data. I tried restarting my RStudio, but perhaps I should restart my computer..?

Comment: That will be a good option

Comment: Still not working. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Can you show `packageVersion("classifierplots")`. I used `1.4.0`

Comment: mine is ```1.3.3```

Comment: I'll try updating the package

Comment: Try updating the package and test it again.

Comment: I have updated everything - R, RStudio, and installed packages. I have finally got my plot to run. Thank you for the help diagnosing the issue.